# Cannot install swagger jar

Tags: command-line, jar, swagger, executable-jar, openapi

I have problem executing the jar installer for swagger. The indications are to use

```
java -jar .\swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.19.jar
```

But I receive this kind of message

```
15:10:11.691 [main] DEBUG io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.SwaggerCodegen - there are not options for command 'langs'
15:10:11.693 [main] DEBUG io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.SwaggerCodegen - there are not options for command 'version'
```

I have not found what these parameter are for, or what is to be done to set them. Have you some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (3.0.22) works for me

```
$ java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.22.jar version
3.0.22

$ java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.22.jar langs
Available languages: [dart, aspnetcore, csharp, csharp-dotnet2, go, go-server, dynamic-html, html, html2, java, jaxrs-cxf-client, jaxrs-cxf, inflector, jaxrs-cxf-cdi, jaxrs-spec, jaxrs-jersey, jaxrs-di, jaxrs-resteasy-eap, jaxrs-resteasy, micronaut, spring, nodejs-server, openapi, openapi-yaml, kotlin-client, kotlin-server, php, python, python-flask, r, scala, scala-akka-http-server, swift3, swift4, swift5, typescript-angular, typescript-axios, typescript-fetch, javascript]
```